# How to make a fieldname dynamic in a javascript filter

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, fields, array, criteria-filter

I have a javascript filter which works fine. I have a field on which I filter an array. What I would like to do is to make this fieldname "Categorie__c" dynamic.

I tried with a concatenate but this doesn't seem to work how can I achieve this

Javascript

```
var  fieldName = component.get("v.fieldName");
var  opleidingfilter = opleidingenList.filter(function(item) { return item.Categorie__c == event.getSource().get('v.text') });
```

Tried

```
var  opleidingfilter = opleidingenList.filter(function(item) { return "item."+fieldName == event.getSource().get('v.text') });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you use the "array" notation, just as if it were an integer value. As a side note, in Lightning you can use the shorter [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax.

```
var fieldName = component.get("v.fieldName"), 
    compareText = event.getSource().get("v.text");
var opleidingfilter = opleidingenList.filter(item => item[fieldName] == compareText);
```

---

I actually realized that I have a copy-paste example that you can view in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/66488eb80292c7151f616ebe7d1b0a18) from a question months ago, except it's dynamic sorting instead of filtering. Please feel free to download it and play around with it.